# Does Ubuntu 16.04 support intel 64 bit processers

Tags: 64-bit, intel, cpu, 16.04

I am using **Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit LTS** for a while and I'd love to try **Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit LTS**. In Ubuntu download page I found 64-bit ISO image as **ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso**, I am bit confused because it mentioned **amd64**.

Can this image **ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso** can be run on **intel 64-bit** processors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`amd64` is the one you want. It works for [both Intel and AMD x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) processors.

The reason it's named `amd64` is because Intel created a 64-bit processor line called Itanium that *wasn't* based on x86, and it didn't do very well. AMD decided instead to base their 64-bit chips on x86, so the name `amd64` was initially used in certain areas like Linux processor type names, and it stuck.

Answer (score 1):

amd64 is the x86 instruction set, so it's Intel as well as AMD. It's also sometimes called x86-64 or x64.

So yes, amd64.iso can run on Intel 64-bit processors, just as i386 works on 32-bit ones.